# Copy Excel Sheet into another Sheet in another Workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript to copy the contents of one sheet in a workbook to a sheet in another workbook. I was going to just copy and paste each individual column as I already know how to copy individual columns but I am assuming there must be an easier way.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about VBA?

Comment: @ Dr. Trey Yeah, I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy the sheet:

```
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("2ndWorkbookName").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```